# How to use cascade.xml for object recognition in openCV

Tags: object, opencv, pattern-matching

I've generated cascade xml in openCV using haar training module.. Now how can I use it for Object recognition.?

Please help.!! _/_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following opencv [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=cascadeclassifier#CascadeClassifier) on Object Detection, you have to create the cascade detector object and `::load` the cascade you want to apply (the xml file you have generated).
`::detectMultiScale` is used to fill a `std::vector<cv::Rect>` of detected object from current frame by sliding windows of different scales and sizes and merging high confident close samples.

Code [here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/raw/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/objectDetection/objectDetection.cpp)!

Comment: Thanks a lot..! It helped..! Can you please guide me on how to use cvCaptureFromFile..?? I actually don't have a cam to test it :(

Comment: cv::Mat img; cv::VideoCapture cap(0); cap >> frame; See http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use haartraining you can use "opencv_performance.exe". You can find it in "opencv\bin...\"
But if you have cascade.xml it's mean you used traincascade. There are no already build bin to check your cascade. You can find example in "opencv\samples\cpp\tutorial_code\objectDetection".